# How to convert an array into an object in javascript with mapped key-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array like so:

```
[ 
  {
    field: "firstname",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    field: "lastname",
    value: "Doe"
  },
  {
    field: "hobbies",
    value: "singing, basketball"
  },
]
```

Now I want to convert it into an object like so where in the key is the `field` and the value is the `value` from the above array:

```
const result = { 
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  hobbies: "Singing, basketball"
}
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please show a more extended example? (e.g. 3 names?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map()` the array to `Object.values` and pass it to [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const arr = [ { field: "firstname", value: "John" }, { field: "lastname", value: "Doe" }, { field: "hobbies", value: "singing, basketball" }, ]

const res = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(Object.values))
console.log(res)
```

The another solution could be using `reduce()`

```js
const arr = [ { field: "firstname", value: "John" }, { field: "lastname", value: "Doe" }, { field: "hobbies", value: "singing, basketball" }, ]

const res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a.field] = a.value,ac),{})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Array.prototype.reduce like so:

```
const arr = [ 
  {
    field: "firstname",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    field: "lastname",
    value: "Doe"
  }
];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => { 
  acc[val.field] = val.value; 
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This would populate the `obj` object with the values and fields.

Comment: This is will not produce correct result. It will get the last value `Doe`. You should return `acc` using `,`. And also `reduce` doesnot modify original array you should assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [
  {field: "firstname", value: "John"},
  {field: "lastname", value: "Doe"}
];

const result = data.reduce((r, {field: key, value}) => (r[key] = value, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with applying simple `for` loop...

```
const arr=[ 
        {
         field: "firstname",
         value: "John"
        },
        {
         field: "lastname",
         value: "Doe"
        }
     ];

const obj={} //declare an object

for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    obj[arr[i].field]=arr[i].value;
  }

alert(obj)  //output : {firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" }
```

Comment: You are declaring implicit globals. You should `let` or `var` before `i` and `const` before `obj` and `arr`