# How to convert an array of objects into an array of objects with mapped key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

It is hard to put into words, so If anyone could help me with the title of the question, thanks in advance. At the end of the day, I have an array like so;

```js
[ 
  {
    field: "firstname",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    field: "lastname",
    value: "Doe"
  },
  {
    field: "hobbies",
    value: "singing, basketball"
  },
]
```

and the desired output will be like below;

```js
[ 
  {
   "firstname":"John"
  },
  {
    "lastname":"Doe"
  },
  {
    "hobbies" :"singing, basketball"
  },
]
```

The closest question I could find similar to mine was this one: [How to convert an array into an object in javascript with mapped key-value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902316/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-in-javascript-with-mapped-key-value-pairs)

Comment: The desired result is of questionable usefulness, compared to a single "person" object with well-known property names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use **map** and return object, where key will be `obj.field` and value as `obj.value`
> i.e. `{[obj.field]: obj.value}`

```js
let output = [ 
    {
        field: "firstname",
        value: "John"
    },
    {
        field: "lastname",
        value: "Doe"
    },
    {
        field: "hobbies",
        value: "singing, basketball"
    },
].map(a => ({[a.field]: a.value}))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Answers which explain code are more often upvoted and less likely to be downvoted that answers which merely regurgitate code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to set the `field` property to the key, and `value` property to the `value`

```js
const data = [ {
    field: "firstname",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    field: "lastname",
    value: "Doe"
  },
  {
    field: "hobbies",
    value: "singing, basketball"
  } ]

let result = data.map(({ field, value }) => ({[field]: value}));

console.log(result)
```